# Which should I use Devise or AuthLogic in Rails 3 for authenticating and creating users via OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, authlogic

I am creating an application where the only way users can create an account and then subsequently login is through OAuth.

I only have *one* Oauth2 authentication source.

Ideally, the User would press one button on my app, ask for their Oauth credentials, and if they are not a user, begin to create a user profile.  If they are a user, log them in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that Devise is an overall superior choice and i personally prefer it for my authentication routines. And it supports oauth2. So i would certainly recommend Devise.

Comment: +1. Definitely check out Omniauth as well. It works perfectly with Devise. Tutorial to set Devise + Omniauth up for Facebook OAuth login: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

Comment: Devise is the way to go if you only want devise for custom accounts.

Comment: I decided to go with Devise --- I guess I should have asked the question differently to clarify the advantages.  But I was able to get it seemingly set up so far but haven't set it up with Omniauth yet....